# Saving dataframes after cleaning in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a collection of JSONs, all of the same format and with the same data irregularities, that I'd like to clean and ultimately convert to dataframes for use within Python.

As I'm doing the same process repeatedly over each JSON, a loop seemed like the most natural solution.

I'm running into an issue in reassigning the dataframes to variables post-cleaning, as there doesn't appear to be a natural way to store them.

I know Python frowns on dynamically creating variable names.  I'd like to avoid using a dictionary or otherwise creating a holder variable to achieve this.  Being that I have a list of variables and a placeholder df, it's not otherwise obvious to me how to assign/name the variables post-cleaning.

Code below.  Any suggestions on how to save the cleaned dataframes at the end of the loop?

```
vars = [a, b, c]

# clean data iteratively
for i in vars:
    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df['value'] = df['value'].replace('.', np.nan).fillna(method='bfill')
    df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'])
    [???] = df
```

Comment: Use a dictionary, define `list_of_df={}` before the for loop, then at the end do `list_of_df[i] = df`.

Comment: For my own curiosity, what is wrong with just appending them to an empty list, such that you have a list of dataframes?

Comment: @FChm, suppose I could...guess I'd imagined having standalone variables.  even with a list, naming would be a challenge though (ie, I'd reference them by index even though they're stand alone data frames where indexes weren't meaningful)

Comment: If the dataframes are completely unrelated you could consider writing them to file, and then loading them when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're looking for, it seems like a simple way would be to enumerate the `vars` list (`vars` is a builtin btw, another name may be better in the long term) and assign back to that list via index.

```
vars = [a, b, c]

# clean data iteratively
for (i,v) in enumerate(vars):
    df = pd.DataFrame(v)
    ...
    vars[i] = df
```

Comment: thanks, and agreed.  had hoped to find a preferable solution than a list of dfs being that the dataframes are of unrelated data.  also, 'vars' is a generic list variable name I created for the example, not present in the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Using a holder variable is completely okay to do. But if you really don't want to create another variable you could overwrite what you have in the list already.

```
vars = [a, b, c]

# clean data iteratively
for index, i in enumerate(vars):
    df = pd.DataFrame(i)
    df['value'] = df['value'].replace('.', np.nan).fillna(method='bfill')
    df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'])
    vars[index] = df
```

Comment: thanks.  thought about that, or even creating another list of dfs.  had hoped for a cleaner solution (ie, one that didn't require a list of otherwise unrelated datasets)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use some sort of a structure to hold the saved cleaned dfs, otherwise you'll just be overwriting them. So a list or a dictionary (or even another df) should do.

Comment: of course, I'm asking about the mechanism for creating/referencing the new dfs